# Animation or Video instead of Default.png (Iphone app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I saw in many application like Zara, Zara Home, D&G.. that instead of using the Default.png image for loading the application, they use a video instead. Did someone know how to do it?
 Did they manage to replace the Default image and put an animation instead or just load an animation in the ApplicationDidFinishLaunching

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just load an animation in applicationDidFinishLaunching and replace the image with it.

Comment: This is true. Especially because there is no way to show anything else until applicationDidFinishLaunching: is called. Apple really forces you to show a Default.png.

Comment: ok thanks, did you have any link or tuto to make animation? I wanna begin work on it. And I like the kind of animation they made. Its a good idea to make an animation for the loading

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController to play a video. CoreAnimation to make an animation. Or use [UIView beginAnimation.....] etc. Lots of info around this site.